# What is this tool with a slotted wrench and threaded nut?

Tags: identify-a-tool

Can anyone help me in identifying this odd thing.
It seems to be some sort of attaching or tensioning "screw"
I have searched the internet as much as i can and now i'm out of ideas as to what it is.

- The plastic handle or tightening tool is 14cm long and slides over the black portion to loosen or tighten.
- The plastic screw is 5cm long and the metal T-bar is 2cm and firmly embedded into the end of the screw.
- The thread width is 1.5cm with a 3mm pitch.
- The black "nut" is 3.7cm diameter at the base and 2.2cm tall.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a tile leveling kit similar to:
[this one](https://www.amazon.ca/Leveling-Construction-Reusable-Flooring-levellers/dp/B07TKB11NN)
[image]

Comment: Many thanks. I actually searched for tiling tools but never saw this.

Comment: I'd be most interested in seeing how this is to be used. Especially since there are 50 in the pack you linked and they claim they are reusable. Not doubting you, I'm doubting _them_!

Comment: To hazard a guess - slip the T-shaped metal bit in the mortar between tiles, rotate 90 degrees, then tighten to pull two adjacent tiles flush with each other. Hopefully the mortar readjusts to not leave a void… Once set, snap off the metal bit and cover with the grout line.

Comment: @FreeMan Short version:  https://youtube.com/shorts/zdLLc9m5b_s?feature=share

Comment: @FreeMan Long version: https://youtu.be/5hfoafbnRTk

Comment: Not exactly a ringing endorsement, but then you were just answering the question, not providing opinions one way or the other. I'd agree with @JonCuster - I wonder how much of a void this might leave by pulling tiles up and how many end up breaking prematurely.